# I'm doing 自己PR, how can I say that I'm a person who doesn't give up?

Tags: grammar, translation, word-requests

I'm doing "自己{じこ}PR" for a school recommendation interview, how can I say that I'm a person who doesn't give up? Like, even if something's difficult, I don't give up. If possible, please make it as simple as possible, I'm only upper elementary.

Answer (score 4):

じこうPR is incorrect and 自己(じこ)PR is correct.

"Don't give up" is translated as "あきらめない". So you can say "私は、どんな困難な状況でも、あきらめません。" and you can simply say "私は、どんな時でもあきらめません."

In addition, another translation of "even if something's difficult" is "どんな苦しい時でも".

Comment: maybe add 絶対 before "あきらめません" for extra emphasis (:

Comment: Yes, it shows strong will.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way that you could express what you want to say. I will give you the parts and then string them together into sentences at the end of this answer. The fragments translate a little bit differently than the full sentence, but such is translation. The translation is a natural English phrase compared to the Japanese phrase. That means I did not translate each word literally, but according to what is being said.

> どんな[難]{むずか}しい[事]{こと}でも、
> "Regardless of the hardships I have to face,"
>
> [最後]{さいご}までなしとげる
> "see things through to the end"
>
> 〜[自信]{じしん}があります。
> "I have confidence that ~." (normal form)
>
> 〜と[自負]{じふ}しております。
> "I have confidence that ~." (humble form [best for resumes and interviews])

⇒

> どんな[難]{むずか}しい[事]{こと}でも、[最後]{さいご}までなしとげられると[自負]{じふ}しております。
> "I have confidence in my ability to see 'things' through to completion regardless of their difficulty."

or

> どんな[難]{むずか}しい[事]{こと}でも、[最後]{さいご}までなしとげる[自信]{じしん}があります。